# How to detect end-of-file for FileHandle.standardInput from Terminal

Tags: swift, nsfilehandle

I have a Swift program that reads from `FileHandle.standardInput` (in Objective-C, this would be `+[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput]`.  It should terminate reading when it hits end-of-file on the input stream, but when I run it using the Terminal (on macOS Sierra) as input, it doesn't detect end-of-file when I hit Ctrl+D.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing.  This program simply reads from standard input and writes what it has read to standard output:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

let input = FileHandle.standardInput
let output = FileHandle.standardOutput

let bufferSize = 1024

var data = input.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
while data.count > 0 {
    output.write(data)
    data = output.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
}
```

I expect `readData(ofLength:)` to return a `Data` object with a `count` of zero when it reaches end of file.

When I run with a file redirected to standard input, like this:

```
./echo.swift < foo.txt
```

It writes out the file and terminates.

However, if I run it like this:

```
./echo.swift
```

and then type some text and hit Ctrl+D, I expect it to treat the Ctrl+D as end-of-file and terminate.  But it doesn't do that.  It just keeps running and echoing lines.  It will eventually terminate if I hit Ctrl+D over and over, but that's not what I want.

Changing the `bufferSize` doesn't seem to help. I get the same behavior if I set it to `1`.

I suspect I need to set some sort of buffering parameter on the `stdin` file descriptor, or the terminal device, or catch a signal, or something, but I don't know what.

I know that I could use the C stdio `fread()` API instead, which properly detects an end-of-file condition from the terminal, or I could use Swift's `readLine(_:)` to read from standard input without worrying about file handles/descriptors, but I want to know if there is a way to do this with `FileHandle` or the raw file descriptor without re-implementing C stdio.

---

Update: After spending an hour reviewing Apple's [LibC source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/), I concluded "It's complicated" and so now I'm just using `fread(..., stdin)` in my program.  But I'd still like to know if there is some simple way to get this to work with `FileHandle`.

Comment: Look into the `readLine` function.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, but I want to figure out how to do this with NSFileHandle. I've updated the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, Swift 5, something like this ...

```
while (FileHandle.standardInput.availableData.count > 0) {
  FileHandle.standardOutput.write(FileHandle.standardInput.availableData)
}
```

Simple and does work almost like a cat program, some stuff to tune for that.

Better with correct behaviour :

```
var data: Data
repeat {
  data = FileHandle.standardInput.availableData
  FileHandle.standardOutput.write(data)
} while (data.count > 0)
```

The doc about it :

> The data currently available through the receiver, up to the the maximum size that can be represented by an NSData object.
>
> If the receiver is a file, this method returns the data obtained by reading the file from the current file pointer to the end of the file. If the receiver is a communications channel, this method reads up to a buffer of data and returns it; if no data is available, the method blocks. Returns an empty data object if the end of file is reached. This method raises NSFileHandleOperationException if attempts to determine the file-handle type fail or if attempts to read from the file or channel fail

Comment: FYI, the docs are at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/1411463-availabledata